# Waiting on Task in NUnit test method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nunit, task-parallel-library

I come across on this test method in NUnit services tests in project I am working at a moment

```
[Test]
public void FindAsync_By_Using_Some_Condition()
{
    //code omitted for clarity ...
    var results = Repository.FindAsync(workClients);

    results.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Result.Count);
}

public async Task<ICollection<T>> FindAsync( FindOptions<T> options )
{
    var output = new List<T>();
   //code omitted for clarity ...

    return await Task.FromResult(output);
}
```

where they have been using Task.Wait before they did assertion. Any particular reason why it was done this way? What would have happened if they omitted Task.Wait (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))?

And why FindAsync_By_Using_Some_Condition() is not used in conjunction with async / await keywords?

Comment: Look at [this](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2013/01/19/async-support-in-nunit) post.

Comment: @Jeroen - why they block Thread for one second? Why one second?

Comment: That is a bad attempt to ensure the success of the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test was probably written before NUnit supported async. With NUnit 2.6.4 or 3.x, it could now be rewritten,

```
[Test]
public async Task FindAsync_By_Using_Some_Condition()
{
    var results = await Repository.FindAsync(workClients);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, they are actually using NUnit 3.0.5813.39031

Comment: But have they always been using NUnit 3? It could be that they updated NUnit, but never went back and updated their tests?

Comment: it 's very likely that they messed up with different versions of NUnit on different environments (dev env, staging, production) and that is a reason why they keep this pattern